# LinqToSQl and adapting from linq to Domain objects in a centralised manner

Tags: linq-to-sql, object, dns, adaption

Imagine the following code:

```
return from a in DBContext.Acts
       join artist in DBContext.Artists
       on a.ArtistID equals artist.ID into art
       from artist in art.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new Shared.DO.Act {
                 ID = a.ID,
                 Name = a.Name,
                 Artist = new Shared.DO.Artist   {
                             ID = artist.ID,
                             Name = artist.Name
                          },
                 GigId = a.GigID
              };
```

As you can see, the linqtosql generated act object is adapted into the Shared.DO.Act object. As part of this a linqtosql generated Artist object is adapted into a Shared.DO.Artist

Elsewhere in my code base, I may want to request an Artist (see below):

```
return from a in DBContext.Artists
       select new Shared.DO.Artist {
                 ID = artist.ID, 
                 Name = artist.Name
              },
              GigId = a.GigID
       };
```

This means the adption code for an Artist now appears in two places! Once when getting an artist and also when an act is loaded

How should I centralise this adaption code?

Comment: Have you tried adding methods that do it in the respective classes. You could use a constructor.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using an Artists class with a dictionary of artists:

```
public class Artists
{
    // key should be whatever type artist.ID is
    private Dictionary<int, Shared.DO.Artist> _artistDictionary;

    public static Get(int id)
    {
        if (_artistDictionary == null) 
            _artistDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Shared.DO.Artist>();

        if (!_artistDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            var artist = from a in DBContext.Artists
                         on a.ID equals id
                         select new Shared.DO.Artist {
                             ID = a.ID, 
                             Name = a.Name
                         };

            _artistDictionary.Add(id, artist);
        }

        return _artistDictionary[id];
    }
}
```